# An anomaly (bug?) in iCal in Lion?

Tags: macos, applications, ical, bug

Has anybody else noticed a problem with date display in iCal in Lion? It appears when "Show event times" is activated in the General tab of Calendar preferences.

I spotted a date-display inconsistency with a weekly recurring event I have set up. Despite having system-wide dates formatted as 12-hour with am/pm included (Language & Text System Preference), this event fails to respect that preference. It is scheduled to commence at 1:00 pm and finish three hours later, at 4:00 pm. Rather than being listed in Calendar in this way, it appears:

- in the summary list in Daily view as "13 to 16", and
- with a starting time of "13" in Daily, Weekly and Monthly view.

Anxious to get to the bottom of this, I have played around with various date ranges in a number of test calendar entries. The conclusion I've arrived at is that the problem is confined to on-the-hour times, as illustrated [here](http://dublinmusicgroup.com/stuff/Calendar%20anomaly.png). Once the time does not end in 00, things display correctly; otherwise, the date displays in stripped-down, 24-hour fashion.

So: *has* anyone else seen this, or am I alone with this problem? I'm inclined to submit bug feedback to Apple, but would first prefer to have corroborating evidence.

Comment: Since posting this question I've searched for any other references to the problem. Interestingly, when just now I asked Google to list matches for "inconsistent time display in iCal in Lion", the top hit was my own question here. An interesting instance of circularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - I'm not getting it and can't seem to break things even trying to.

An official bug might be warranted as you seem to have been careful to be sure it's happening. I would be very certain to file if you can make a new account and the same happens in a clean calendar.

Comment: Why is it, I wonder, that I so seldom remember to test with a new account? Anyway, I've done that now and the inconsistency persists. I thought at first that all was well with the new account, but that was only because the default time format is 24-hour rather than 12. Once I switched to 12-hour in System Preferences the new account behaved just as my principal one does. I'm leaning towards submitting a bug report, but will hold off until I install Lion on a second machine. It's possible that this one hasn't been totally happy with the upgrade from Snow Leopard to Lion.